# Ubuntu installation on disk already dual boot formatted

Tags: installation

I have an older Toshiba laptop (about 6 years old) formatted for SUSE 11.2 and Windows XP for dual boot.  I want to reformat the hard drive and to install Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS as the sole operating system.  I have an open USB port.  I can also use a USB flash drive to load the Ubuntu installation files to either current hard disk partition.  I can also use a portable hard disk as the source for installation files.  Finally, I could make a DVD which I think the laptop could read.  (It will certainly read CDs, but I'm not totally sure about DVDs.)

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I have a Dell Latitude D610 laptop that is old, and what worked for me was a disc. I downloaded the 32 bit ubuntu from the ubuntu website, and then I burned it to a blank 700mb disc. You want to make shore that the boot sequence is set to boot from cd. After this it is pretty self explaining.

Take care...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to download the ISO file from the [Ubuntu website](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop). If you are not sure if your drive will read DVD, make a bootable USB to install Ubuntu – the ISO image won’t fit in a CD.

To make a bootable USB you can follow the instructions for Windows [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows), or use Netbootin on Linux (I’m not sure about OpenSUSE repositories). If you had another Ubuntu system near you, it would be just easy for you with Ubuntu pre-installed Startup Disk Creator.

In the installation process, select **Something Else**.

I recommend you to have a separate home partition, so delete all partitions except the SWAP, then make an at least 15-20GB one for ext4 File System and select **/** for its mount point. The rest can be your home partition, so format it to ext4 and select **/home** for its mount point.

That’s it! Now you can click on the install button.